# Regular expression one letter followed by at least one numerical value

Tags: c#, regex

I try to create a regular expression that match the following..

The name starts with a letter and followed by at least 1 numerical value. For example this should be valid: "w1234.pdf" but not this: "ww1234.pdf". So far I only have this:

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{1}?$
```

Comment: Try `^[a-zA-Z][0-9].*$` or just `^[a-zA-Z][0-9]`

Comment: The symbol `{1}` means "ExactlyOne". So to match your condition, witch is "AtLeastOne", on regex "sounds" `{1,}` "OneOrMore", or simle `+` "AtLeastOne". So `[a-zA-Z][0-9]+`

Comment: I love when people get there answer and don't mark any of answers as right :)

Comment: Why is `^[a-zA-Z][0-9].+$` accepted? It contains one more requirement: there should be at least 3 chars in the string (or there should be at least one more char after the digit). This has not been mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex matches one character in the range `[a-zA-Z]`, followed by one digit. Note that `{1}?` is useless in this case, since `[0-9]` already matches one digit.

Change your regex to:

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9].+$
```

if you want to match one digit or more after the first character.

Answer (score 1):

For

> The name **starts** with a **letter** and followed by at least 1 **numerical
>   value**

you can try

```
 ^[a-zA-Z][0-9]
```

pattern. Explanation:

```
^        starting anchor
[a-zA-Z] single letter
[0-9]    followed by a digit
```

Please, notice that valid names are *wider class* than provided in the question, e.g `a1x456.txt`  - *starting* with a *letter* (`a`) followed by at least one numerical value (`1`)